# Lion drag and drop with trackpad?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad

I have tap to click enabled. Is there a gesture that I can use to drag and drop? (especially in Finder). I do not want to over-ride the new three finger swipe for dektop change.

Answer (score 1):

In Lion, you can enable traditional trackpad dragging in System Preferences > Universal Access > Mouse & Trackpad (tab) > Trackpad Options (button at bottom). You can also choose whether to use Drag Lock.

This is also where you go for various scrolling options (enable/disable, inertia, speed).

Answer (score 0):

You could click the button (the hardware trackpad button, thumb works best) to "lock" onto something and then move another finger around to drag around.